# How To Persist Data via API JSON SYMFONY 3

Tags: android, json, rest, api, symfony

Ok so i have one entity called : `Commande` . with attributs :
Titre ,
Auteur ,
Categorie ,
Editeur,
Prix.

I want to create an API REST json in symfony 3 who allow any device (Android for example) to persist datas in this Entity .

for example , In my RestController , this code Allow me to recover datas from another Enity : `Livres`

```
<?php

namespace BiblioBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class BiblioRestController extends Controller
{
public function getListeAction(){
$Livres = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BiblioBundle:Livres')->findAll();
if(!$Livres){
  throw $this->createNotFoundException();
}
return $Livres;
}
}
```

The API adresse is : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/liste.json`

How to do it ?
Thx .

Commande.php :

```
<?php

namespace BiblioBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

/**
* Commande
* @ORM\Table(name="commande")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BiblioBundle\Repository\CommandeRepository")
* 
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Commande
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Titre", type="string", length=80)
 * @Expose
 */
private $titre;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Auteur", type="string", length=50)
 * @Expose
 */
private $auteur;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Categorie", type="string", length=60)
 * @Expose
 */
private $categorie;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Editeur", type="string", length=70)
 * @Expose
 */
private $editeur;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="Prix", type="string", length=30)
 * @Expose
 */
private $prix;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titre
 *
 * @param string $titre
 *
 * @return Commande
 */
public function setTitre($titre)
{
    $this->titre = $titre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titre
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitre()
{
    return $this->titre;
}

/**
 * Set auteur
 *
 * @param string $auteur
 *
 * @return Commande
 */
public function setAuteur($auteur)
{
    $this->auteur = $auteur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get auteur
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuteur()
{
    return $this->auteur;
}

/**
 * Set categorie
 *
 * @param string $categorie
 *
 * @return Commande
 */
public function setCategorie($categorie)
{
    $this->categorie = $categorie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get categorie
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCategorie()
{
    return $this->categorie;
}

/**
 * Set editeur
 *
 * @param string $editeur
 *
 * @return Commande
 */
public function setEditeur($editeur)
{
    $this->editeur = $editeur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get editeur
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEditeur()
{
    return $this->editeur;
}

/**
 * Set prix
 *
 * @param string $prix
 *
 * @return Commande
 */
public function setPrix($prix)
{
    $this->prix = $prix;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prix
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrix()
{
    return $this->prix;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for suggestions? What have you tried? The answer to this could be quite a lot of code...

Comment: I just want to know what is the syntaxt for creating an API REST  in my restController that allow a external device or program (Android , Postman) to persist datas . Just that . Not the full code

Comment: Have you looked at the [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html) already?

Comment: yes , thx i have found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database)

So what you're looking for is something like

```
$commande = new Commande();
$commande->setAuthor('john doe');
//... use the rest of your setters as needed
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($commande);
$em->flush();
return new Response('Saved new commande with id '.$commande->getId());
```

Comment: Thx but i know this is how we persist data in an Object using symfony 3 . But i want to persist via an API Rest format json , with method post , for example .

Comment: my bad , sorry , i found the solution , thanks for your help